# 301 redirecting a rewritten URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I'm attempting to redirect some rewritten URL's but while the redirect is working, it is including the original parameter before the rewrite.

e.g. Redirect /used-cars.html http://www.odins.co.uk/our-cars.html

The rewritten URL is based upon the following structure:

```
http://www.domain.co.uk/pages/index.php?p=used-cars
```

However, what is happening is this:

```
http://www.domain.co.uk/our-cars.html?p=used-cars
```

The .htaccess file is as follows:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^odins.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.odins.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /pages/index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]*)$ /pages/news/index.php?n=$1 [L]

Redirect /used-cars.html http://www.domain.co.uk/our-cars.html
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Paul